# Can we set Pan boundaries for UIImageView in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

Experts!!!

In my project, I am using storyboard.So in viewController's view divided into two parts
one for:iAd, 2nd for:Uiview where to pan my UIImageView.
my code at handlePan: is

```
- (void) handlePanGestures:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)paramSender{
if (paramSender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded && paramSender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed){

CGPoint location = [paramSender locationInView:self.mainView];//here mainView is Pan area..

[paramSender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.mainView];
paramSender.view.center = location; }
}
```

But by this code I unable to get what I want.. Please suggest me in this case..

Answer (score 0):

Please enable your UIImageViews userInteraction

```
[imageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

If you have already done this and this method gets called when you are panning the image view, but still nothing is happening. Try this code

```
CGpoint location = [paramSender translationinView:self.mainView];
[paramSender.view setCenter:location];
```

Hope I helped.